# Struct tag alias

Tags: c, struct

Is there a way to alias a struct tag? As in, I have a `struct foo` and want to alias it to `struct bar`. I tried `typedef struct foo struct bar`, `typedef struct foo bar`, etc... but it doesn't work of course because `foo` and `bar` are not type names but tags.

Is there a way to do this without defining actual type names for my structures (I would like to keep them as tags as I am partial to prefixing them with `struct` - please, no religious wars over this).

My guess is tags must be unique and so it isn't possible directly but I curiously could not find a reference online (all I find are, unsurprisingly, discussions about what typedef struct means and when/why to use it, which again isn't what I'm looking for).

Comment: sounds confusing when reading a program where you see struct foo but it actually means struct bar. makes the code harder to read IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `#define bar foo` to achieve what you want. Don't know if it's good enough for you, but it works, as it does in the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo {
    int a;
};

#define bar foo

int main( ) {

    struct bar x;

    x.a = 10;
    printf( "%d", x.a );

    putchar( 10 );
    return 0;
}
```

It has one downside I can tell, which is that right now you can define, let's say, an integer with the identifier name `foo`, but attempting to do so with the name `bar` will again result in a variable with the identifier name `foo`, since that's how `#define` works.

Comment: Ah, hadn't thought of #define'ing the actual struct tag, it never occurred to me somehow. I think conflicts with identifiers that just happen to have the same identifier as the tag should not be a problem, the tag is all-caps and likely will never conflict with anything. But I'll check it out. Other suggestions welcome though!

Comment: @Thomas I don't think there is another way. Other suggestions won't show up :p

Answer (score 0):

You can't `typedef` one struct into another but you can use `typedefs` to create sereval type names that point to the same type.

In similar cases what's usually being done is to use 2 `typedef` of the same struct:

```
// the one and only struct definition
struct foo {
};

// define the new types which are equivalent to struct foo
typedef struct foo foo;
typedef struct foo bar;
```

The code can either `foo` or `bar` but not `struct foo`.

Comment: As an additional piece of information, those two type definitions can be combined together as in `typedef struct foo foo, bar;`. On top of that, all three can be combined together as in `typedef struct foo { } foo, bar;`. Lastly, empty structures are not part of specification as far as I know, and is just a [GCC extension to C](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Empty-Structures.html).